# How to use block_diag repeatedly

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have rather simple question but still couldn´t make it work. 
I want a block diagonal n^2*n^2 matrix. The blocks are sparse n*n matrices with just the diagonal, first off diagonals and forth off diag. For the simple case of `n=4` this can easily be done

```
datanew = ones((5,n1))
datanew[2] = -2*datanew[2]
diagsn = [-4,-1,0,1,4]
DD2 = sparse.spdiags(datanew,diagsn,n,n)
new = sparse.block_diag([DD2,DD2,DD2,DD2])
```

Since this only useful for small n's, is there a way better way to use block_diag? Thinking of n -> 1000

Comment: I cleaned up your display a bit.  You need to be more specific about why this does not work as well with larger `n`.  (what is `n1`?)  `block_diag` and `bmat` are open Python code, so you can study them, if needed streamline the action to fit your case.

Comment: `bmat` ends up converting your `DD2` to `coo` format, joining their `data`, `row`, `col` into 3 big arrays, and making a new `coo` from that.

Comment: the point is I don't wanna write down block_diag(DD2,.......,DD2) a thousend times, sure it will work, but isn't there something like block_diag((DD2,:) till n) ?

Comment: A crude approach is to append `DD2` to a list a thousand times, and pass that list to `block_diag`.

Comment: Will this work in block_diag ? I'm not sure if it will accept a list

Comment: In my version the doc is: `block_diag(mats, format=None, dtype=None)`.  `mats` is a list.  I edited your question to reflect that.  But even if your version expects `block_diag(mat1, mat2, ...)` you could use `block_diag(*alist)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way of constructing a long list of `DD2` matrices, is with a list comprehension:

```
In [128]: sparse.block_diag([DD2 for _ in range(20)]).A
Out[128]: 
array([[-2,  1,  0, ...,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 1, -2,  1, ...,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  1, -2, ...,  0,  0,  0],
       ..., 
       [ 0,  0,  0, ..., -2,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  1, -2,  1],
       [ 0,  0,  0, ...,  0,  1, -2]])

In [129]: _.shape
Out[129]: (80, 80)
```

At least in my version, `block_diag` wants a list of arrays, not `*args`:

```
In [133]: sparse.block_diag(DD2,DD2,DD2,DD2)
...
TypeError: block_diag() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)

In [134]: sparse.block_diag([DD2,DD2,DD2,DD2])
Out[134]: 
<16x16 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 40 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

This probably isn't the fastest way to construct such a block diagonal array, but it's a start.

================

Looking at the code for `sparse.block_mat` I deduce that it does:

```
In [145]: rows=[]
In [146]: for i in range(4):
    arow=[None]*4
    arow[i]=DD2
    rows.append(arow)
   .....:     

In [147]: rows
Out[147]: 
[[<4x4 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 10 stored elements (5 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>,
  None,
  None,
  None],
 [None,
  <4x4 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
  ...
  None,
  <4x4 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 10 stored elements (5 diagonals) in DIAgonal format>]]
```

In other words, `rows` is a 'matrix' of `None` with `DD2` along the diagonals.  It then passes these to `sparse.bmat`.

```
In [148]: sparse.bmat(rows)
Out[148]: 
<16x16 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int32'>'
    with 40 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

`bmat` in turn collects the `data,rows,cols` from the `coo` format of all the input matricies, joins them into master arrays, and builds a new `coo` matrix from them.

So an alternative is to construct those 3 arrays directly.