# Buildin a sparse 2D laplacian matrix using SciPy modules

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I need to construct the 2D laplacian which looks like this:

[image: 2D_Laplacian]

, where

[image]

, and I is the identity matrix. So far, I have done it using the [diags method of scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.diags.html#scipy.sparse.diags), but I wonder whether there is a smarter way to do it using the [block_diag method](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.block_diag.html#scipy.sparse.block_diag). Has anyone tried to build the 2D laplacian with this method?

My current method to create this is by this function:

```
from scipy.sparse import diags
# Defining the size of the matrix
nx = 3
ny = 3
N  = nx*ny
main_diag = [-4.0 for i in xrange(N)]
side_diag = []
for i in xrange(1,N):
    if i%4 == 0:
        side_diag.append(0)
    else:
        side_diag.append(1)
up_down_diag = [1.0 for i in xrange(N-4)]
diagonals = [main_diag,side_diag,side_diag,up_down_diag,up_down_diag]
laplacian = diags(diagonals, [0, -1, 1,nx,-nx], format="csr")
print laplacian.toarray()
```

Comment: Please show your current method, so we don't accidentally suggest the same thing again :)

Comment: ``diads` is good, but you should be able to use numpy methods to create the elelments of the `diagonals` list.  I've also used `coo` for this kind of layout.

Comment: I get an error when I run your code: ValueError: Diagonal length (index 3: 5 at offset 3) does not agree with matrix size (9, 9).

Comment: [Numerical Recipes pages 1028-1029](http://apps.nrbook.com/empanel/index.html?pg=1029) has nice diagrams and explanation of Laplacian matrices.  (Beware: some functions for this have args `nx, ny`, some `ny, nx`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I replaced your use of lists with arrays:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse

nx, ny = 3, 3
N  = nx*ny
main_diag = np.ones(N)*-4.0
side_diag = np.ones(N-1)
side_diag[np.arange(1,N)%4==0] = 0
up_down_diag = np.ones(N-3)
diagonals = [main_diag,side_diag,side_diag,up_down_diag,up_down_diag]
laplacian = sparse.diags(diagonals, [0, -1, 1,nx,-nx], format="csr")
print laplacian.toarray()
```

producing

```
[[-4.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1. -4.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1. -4.  1.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  1. -4.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0. -4.  1.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  1. -4.  1.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1. -4.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  1. -4.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.  0. -4.]]
```

Is the [1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0] pattern for the side diagonal right?

For a small example like this it may run the same speed, but with large dimensions using arrays rather than lists should be faster - plus it is more consistent with numpy code underlying sparse.

With uniform diagonals like this `diags` looks pretty good.

I've only played with the block format for one other SO question.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34124377/901925

`coo` is good for matricies composed of overlapping smaller ones, such as in finite element stiffness.  But recasting your diagonals into `coo` is tedious.

For what it's worth, `sparse.diags` uses `dia_matrix`, having converted the list of diagonals into the `dia` `data` matrix.  You could look at that, but its layout isn't as obvious.  To make a `csr` matrix, `diags` converts this `dia` format to `coo`, and then on to `csr`.  But normally you shouldn't worry about all these conversions.  Use the format that makes most sense in your problem, and let `sparse` handle the conversion details.

If you want to explore block format more, you need to outline how your problem can be viewed as blocks.

Comment: The pattern for the side diagonals is wrong - in case of 3x3 it should be [1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1]

Comment: So it needs to use `side_diag[np.arange(1,N)%nx==0] = 0`.  Or in you version `if i%nx == 0:`

Answer (score 3):

N-dimensional laplacians can be expressed as Kronecker product of 1D laplacians:

```
import scipy.sparse as sp
def laplacian2D(N):
    diag=np.ones([N*N])
    mat=sp.spdiags([diag,-2*diag,diag],[-1,0,1],N,N)
    I=sp.eye(N)
    return sp.kron(I,mat,format='csr')+sp.kron(mat,I)
```

[Connectivity pattern of 2D Laplacian - img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHQ6A.jpg)